# Drag and rotate a set of paths in Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

First off, is there any way to access one of the path "lines" you create from this method: `paper.path("M 250 250 l 0 -50 l -50 0 l 0 -50 l -50 0 l 0 50 l -50 0 l 0 50 z");`? That creates an 8-sided shape and I need to have one of the side's stroke color be different.

I couldn't find a way so I ended up doing this:

```
r = paper.set();

r.push(
    paper.path("M0 0L0 50"),
    paper.path("M0 50L125 50"),
    paper.path("M125 50L125 0"),
    paper.path("M125 0L0 0")
);
```

That creates 4 lines that make up a rectangle. I need a way to drag these types of shapes around, the drag would start if you click and hold anywhere in a "contained" area inside the paths. I also need a way to rotate an entire set of paths and be able to drag them without the coordinate system rotating as well. I'm using the latest version of Raphael (2.0).

Comment: I am also working on a test project that uses Raphael to create shape and drag/resize/rotate them... I started using a path and gave up as I find it to be quite a pain, more so when you try to do a resize (which has to be a scale for paths) and it losing precision with positioning when this happens (well it did for me). I am now going back to basic shapes (rectangle) though I am considering recreating and forcing a redraw for path controls when they are modified (the I can better handle my resize etc.) but I am worried about losing some of the great functionality with events etc... not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To help with second question, [Raphael.Freetransform](https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.FreeTransform) handles dragging, rotating and scaling of individual elements and sets.